# folder action not triggered after macos catalina update

Tags: macos-catalina, finder

I had a folder action, to add multiple tags, when files are added to a folder.
Ever since Catalina update, this fails...
In automator, I get it to work, if i use the "get finder items" for testing purposes.

When I add a file to the folder itself, nothing happens.

**privacy and security settings**

- **automator** has full disk access
- **FolderActionsDispatcher.app** has access to

  - my network volumes
  - in **automation** it has access to **finder**

```
property ca : current application
property tagname : {"tag_1", "tag_2", "tag_3", "tag_4", "tag_5"}

use framework "foundation"
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite 10.10 or later required
use scripting additions

on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with anItem in input
        set_tag(anItem, tagname)
    end repeat
    return input
end run

on set_tag(theFile, atag)
    set tagArray to ca's NSArray's arrayWithArray:atag
    set fileURL to ca's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:(POSIX path of theFile)
    fileURL's setResourceValue:tagArray forKey:(ca's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
end set_tag
```

After looking on the internet, I didn't find an answer. So I hope someone here could help me.

**print screen of the workflow**
[image: automator workflow]

Comment: what are you passing in to this AppleScript action? An array of files, I assume? You might try `set_tag(get anItem, tagname)` or `set_tag(contents of anItem, tagname)`, which should force the handler call to pass by value rather than pass by reference.

Comment: also, fyi, you've defined `tagname` as a global property, so you don't need to pass it in your handler call. The handler can already see the global property.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @TedWrigley  
unfortunately, neither of these proposals resolves the issue  
  
When I get it to work again, as in pre-catalina, I will look into changing the variable to either local or no longer pass it. But I'm not going to make 2 changes at once, it would make troubleshooting harder :)

to answer your question: 1 or more files

Comment: in automator, it works; i added the action "get finder items".  So the problem isn't the script, but the script not being triggered anymore on adding a file to the folder.

Comment: Can you show the automator workflow you're using?

Comment: added print screen in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try quiting the "folderActionsDispatcher" process in Activity Monitor. When my folder actions don't fire, its usually because this process isn't firing for some reason.[image]